# MS Access to MS SQL Linked data - extremely long updates & deletes?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access application with data in a separate access mdb. We need to move the data to MS SQL. Previously when I did this is worked very well - dramatic speed improvements. In this new upgrade however, we are seeing some problems with translating of the SQL from Access to SQL.

We have the solution separated into an APP mdb and a DATA MDB. We use Linked-tables to join the two. After migrating the data to SQL server, we created an ODBC link, then re-pointed the linked-tables to the SQL data source over ODBC.  We would expect the SQL command generated by Access, to be simply transferred to SQL server, for SQL server to operate on same using its normal efficiency and power.

When I put a trace on SQL Profiler, instead of seeing for example a simple "Delete * from table", we see a series of delete statements, one for each record in the table ...

We see the same thing for updates - where we would expect for example "insert into table1 (select a,b,c from table2)...) to be sent as an SQL string, to be executed on the server, we instead see a series of insert statements, one per row being inserted, being sent to the server.

It seems that Access is trying to work out the logic for everything but select statements client side and not letting MS SQL server take care of things as one would expect.

Anyone experienced this behaviour before and can offer a suggestion to resolve?

thanks.

Comment: it's unclear how the abnormal queries relate to the migration effort. Could you describe the timeline? Are the queries initiated by an external app on the SQL Server, where they are forwarded onto MS Access? Or is it the MS Access app shooting queries at the Access tables linked to SQL Server?

Comment: I added comments about how the two are linked together:  "We have the solution separated into an APP mdb and a DATA MDB. We use Linked-tables to join the two. After migrating the data to SQL server, we created an ODBC link, then re-pointed the linked-tables to the SQL data source over ODBC. " - hope this makes the situation clearer, thanks.

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming you confirmed it's the actual app that is sending the requests individually, e.g. by issuing the queries manually?

Comment: You are correct, I have checked this. I opened an SQL query window in Access, and the query goes through to SQL cleanly. If I do it via the query-builder in access however, it plays silly beggers....